# Equivariant De Rham theorem for orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, equivariant-cohomology, orbifolds

Recall that the "classical" equivariant De Rham theorem states that, for a compact Lie group $G$ acting on a compact smooth manifold $M$,
$$H_G^*(M,\mathbb{R})\cong H^*(\Omega_G(M)),$$
where $H_G^*(M,\mathbb{R})$ is the cohomology of the Borel construction $(M\times E)/G$, and $\Omega_G(M)$ is the Cartan complex $((S\mathfrak{g}^*\otimes\Omega(M))^G,d_{\mathfrak{g}})$.

I this also valid when $M$ is an orbifold?

Comment: I do not know anything about equivarinat deRham theorem but I find this interesting... I know what is an orbifold and what is deRham theorem in general.. most of that makes sense but I don’t understand where does $E$ come from? What is $E$ there? This might be clear for experts,, I am just asking out of curiosity.. what is $d_{\mathfrak{g}}$, I know $\mathfrak{g}$ is Lie algebra of $G$... Edit : Some search says your $E$ is $EG$ which is total space of universal principal $G$ bundle.. Is that correct..

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: Quotients by free actions are nicer than quotients by non-free actions. For every group G, there is a contractible, free G-space EG, so given another G-space X you can form a free G-space $X\times EG$ (with the diagonal action) homotopy equivalent to X. The quotient $X_G=(X\times EG)/G$ (Borel space) is extremely useful. Its cohomology is called the G-equivariant cohomology of X. For example, if X is a single point, with the trivial G-action, you still get an interesting Borel space (usually called BG, the classifying space of G).

Comment: As you observed, the quotient $EG\to BG$ is a fibre bundle with fibre G (universal principal G-bundle).

Comment: @JonnyEvans ok.. So, you are saying, suppose $G$ is a Lie group acting on a smooth manifold $X$ Possibly not free action... now,I want to construct a space with two conditions... First is that it is homotopic to $X$ and second is that it has a free $G$ action... you are saying that space is $X\times EG$... Now, consider the quotient space $X_G=(X\times EG)/G$... the cohomology of this space is what we call as equivriant cohomology of $X$.. is that correct....

Comment: Yes, except that X can be any topological space (not necessarily a manifold) and G any topological group (not necessarily a Lie group) acting continuously on X. Note that EG is usually infinite-dimensional (as is the Borel space).